# If exists $\epsilon >0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon<x_n<n^k$ for all $n$ big enough, prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

First off all, i looked to n=1. So, we had $\epsilon<x_1<1$. Then, i'm start to think that the $\sqrt[n]{x_n}$ is in $(\epsilon,1)$ interval and is monotonous crescent(so, converges). But it's not so clear to me cause, if we look to n=2, we have $\epsilon<\sqrt[2]{x_2}<2^k$ and nothing guarantees me that this is in $(\epsilon,1)$.

Comment: You're right. Unless $k = 1$, nothing guarantees that $\sqrt[n]{x_n}$ should be less than $1$. And nothing guarantees that $k$ has to be $1$. Also, If $k$ happens to be $2$, it's supposed to be "$\varepsilon < x_n < n^2$ for all $n$ big enough". No $x_2$, no square root, and $n^2$ rather than $2^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every positive integer $n$ the function $f_n$ defined by 
$$f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$$
is increasing over $(0,\infty)$, therefore from the inequalities
$$
\epsilon <x_n<n^k,
$$
we deduce that
$$
f_n(\epsilon)<f_n(x_n)<f_n(n^k)
$$
That is
$$
\epsilon^{1/n}<\sqrt[n]{x_n}<n^{k/n}
$$
Notice that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \epsilon^{1/n}&=&\epsilon^0=1\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{k/n}&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{k\ln(n)}{n}}=e^0=1
\end{eqnarray}
It follows from the Squeeze Theorem that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}=1
$$

Comment: Man, looks like a simple and great solution. Thx a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h>0$. Suppose $\sqrt[n]{x_n}>1+h$ for infinitely many $n$. Then for these $n$,  $$\begin{align}x_n-n^k&>(1+h)^n-n^k\\&\ge 1+nh+{n\choose 2}h^2+\cdots +{n\choose k+1}h^{k+1}-n^k.\end{align}$$ 
The last expression, viewed as a function of $n$, is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ with leading coefficient $\frac{h^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}>0$. Hence for all big enough $n$ among our infinitely many $n$, we have $x_n-n^k>0$, contradiction.
We conclude that $\limsup\sqrt[n]{x_n}\le 1$.

Can you see why also $\liminf\sqrt[n]{x_n}\ge 1$?

Comment: Yes man, i'm tried in the other way but that's look so good too. thx for the help.